# Keep element in original position after scaling from center JS

Tags: javascript, html

no matter how hard i try, the divs always change possition when i rescale it the first time AND ONLY THE FIRST. i want it to scale on it's original position and stay where it is.
my html :

```
        <div id="rub4" class="rub-for-size">
        <div id="t-loisir" class="div-title">
            <h2>LOISIR</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="loisir_imgs">
            <figure id="travel_img">
                <img src="img/travel.png" class="rub4_img">
                <figcaption>Voyage</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var fig1 = document.getElementById("travel_img");
fig1.addEventListener("mouseover", Zoom1);
fig1.addEventListener("mouseleave", unZoom1);
function Zoom1(){
    // fig1.style.transformOrigin = "50 50";
    // fig1.style.transform = "translate(50px,50px)"
    fig1.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
    
}
function unZoom1(){
    // fig1.style.transformOrigin = "0 0";
    // fig1.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    fig1.style.transform = "translate(0.5%)"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

The element you are trying to resize `travel_img`, which is a `figure` tag, is a block element. So it's resizing much more than just the image.

I'm not entirely clear what the problem is, but have you tried to move the `travel_img` id to the `<img>` tag?

As so:

```
            <figure>
                <img id="travel_img" src="img/travel.png" class="rub4_img">
                <figcaption>Voyage</figcaption>
            </figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you only want to do the scaling once. I declared a counter whose value determines the scaling. Maybe that what you meant?

[Javascript]

```js
         const fig1 = document.getElementById("travel_img");
         let counter = 0;
    
    
         fig1.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
             if (!counter) {
                fig1.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
                counter++;
                fig1.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                    fig1.style.transform = "translate(0.5%)";
                });
             }
         });
```

Comment: i believe that you didn't quite understand my issue. i'm sorry for not expressing it any better. the issue here is that when i hover the fig, it switches it's original position and stays fixed in a new position (after that the function works like a charm). any idea why that may be ?